# how to resolve CodeSign error in appcelerator 4.x

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am getting the following error when I try to package my application for adhoc distribution. I am building fine - but not able to package. I have a indie seat license.

```
[ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CodeSign build/Products/Release-iphoneos/xyz.app
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 1
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/User/.appcelerator/install/5.0.3/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:89:66)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
```

My system -

```
    OS - Mac OSX El-Capitan
    Appcelerator - 4.x
    Appcelerator - Indie license
```

What I have done to debug this issue ? after spending a lot of time researching this - I have

- rebooted the system several times
- appc logout / appc login several times
- appc setup to ensure that I have the latest files (I only work on iOS)
- revoked all my certificates on developer.
- deleted my login-keychain - and rebooted my mac book pro and re-logged in.
- deleted all certificated in ~/Library/MobileDevice/*/*
- recreated all certifcates on https://developer.apple.com/

  - ios developer certificates
  - ios distribution certificates
  - ios developer provisioning certificates
  - ios distribution provisioning certificates

  for the app ID that is described in tiapp.xml

  - downloaded all of these - and installed them by clicking on them
  - I created the csr on my machine new - so I have that also. I also imported that certificates as a private certificates
- checked in the "package configuration - manage section" that all of the certificates are accurate - atleast they show up as a the same name.
- my App is registered in Appcelerator portal

PLEASE HELP - there is no clear description on what the problem is and how to resolve it.

Comment: Do you use the CLI or Studio? Could you follow http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Troubleshooting-section-43299941_AppceleratorCLITroubleshooting-SubmittingaBug to enable debug+trace logging to see if that gets you more information?

Comment: Are you using the Facebook Module? That's what was causing this for me. It had to do with bitcode support. Check the build log file inside your project (go to the finder and enter your project, then go into the build folder, it should be right in there). Usually the last line will tell you exactly what's wrong. 

Also, make sure if you updated Xcode to 7 or above (or are building for iOS 9), you have to build your projects with 5.0.0GA or higher, otherwise you'll get this error it seems (at least I did).

Answer (score 1):

> I know it has been a while for this question but this might help
>   someone.

I’ve been facing this problem for 2 days now:

```
[ERROR] :   BUILD FAILED
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :      CodeSign build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WYN.
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

What I did to solve it was:

- Remove all my certificates from keychain (login and system) and
  revoking them from Apple member center.
- Remove the provisioning profile associated to my app (Apple member
  center).
- Create a new certificate.
- By default it was put in the system area of key chain (That might be
  the problem).
- Copy it to the login area of keychain and remove the old one.
- Associate the provisioning profile to your app.
- Test the app on a device.
- It should be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this issue and found a simple solution that doesn't involve wiping out everything and starting fresh:

1. Browse to the Appcelerator project's build/iphone folder.
2. Open XCode from the *.xcodeproj file
3. Inside XCode, click on the "General" settings of the app, from the icon at the top of the file hierarchy.
4. Under "Signing", checkmark the box to allow XCode to "Automatically manage signing".
5. Build the app once to your test device from within XCode, then exit.
6. Go back to Appcelerator and do Clean then Build to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel For this life saving answer.